# How to troubleshoot BLE Sim (Peripheral simulator) from Google Store on Samsung S9 not discoverable by Garmin watches

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, garmin

I have three Samsung S9 running Android 8 and all have the BLE Sim installed.  One of the S9 while using the app advertising as a heartbeat monitor, it can be successfully discovered by a Garmin 6X and Tactix Delta Solar, while the other two S9 running the same operation do not get discovered by the two watches.  Has anyone run into something similar with advertising Android phones as BLE peripheral and having inconsistent results?  I would expect the same app and same model phones would produce same results.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the three Samsung devices that you have all with the same model number/OS version? From: https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s9-8966.php there are 5 different model numbers for the various regions.

Comment: Yes, all three have the same exact model number SM-G960U1 and Android version 8.0.0.  It doesn't really make sense to me.